# How to format the same name value into an array

Tags: python, arrays, json, printing

I have this JSON Data

```
  {
    "Label": "Color Roles",
    "Pool": "Colors",
    "Hidden": false,
    "Limit": -3,
    "Message": "Pick a colored role to start with <3",
    "Roles": [
      {
        "Name": "Apple★",
        "Print": "Apple",
        "Aliases": ".iam Apple",
        "Aliases1": [
          ".iam Apple",
          "+Apple"
        ]
      },
      {
        "Name": "Clementine★",
        "Print": "Clementine",
        "Aliases": [
          ".iam Clementine",
          "+Clementine"
        ]
      },
      {
        "Name": "Sunflower★",
        "Print": "Sunflower",
        "Aliases": [
          ".iam Sunflower",
          "+Sunflower"
        ]
      },
      {
        "Name": "Mint★",
        "Print": "Mint",
        "Aliases": [
          ".iam Mint",
          "+Mint"
        ]
      },
      {
        "Name": "Ocean★",
        "Print": "Ocean",
        "Aliases": [
          ".iam Ocean",
          "+Ocean"
        ]
      },
      {
        "Name": "Grape★",
        "Print": "Grape",
        "Aliases": [
          ".iam Grape",
          "+Grape"
        ]
      },
      {
        "Name": "Candy Floss★",
        "Print": "Candy Floss",
        "Aliases": [
          ".iam Candy Floss",
          "+Candy Floss"
        ]
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

I want to format all `"Name` within `"Roles"` into an Array then print. I can only print the first "Name" using the code

```
print(data['roles'][0]['name'])
```

How can I get it to format so it'd print

```
["Apple★","Clementine★","Sunflower★","Mint★","Ocean★","Grape★","Candy Floss★"]
```

Then save that data in the array to use for another function which would act as

```
values = ["Apple★","Clementine★","Sunflower★","Mint★","Ocean★","Grape★","Candy Floss★"]
info = requests.get(https://api.url.com/{Values?}
```

just to do a request with each value in a loop

Answer (score 1):

You can use a list comprehension over the `Roles` dicts to get the `Name` properties:

```py
values = [role['Name'] for role in data['Roles']]
```

Output (for your sample data):

```
["Apple★", "Clementine★", "Sunflower★", "Mint★", "Ocean★", "Grape★", "Candy Floss★"]
```

Comment: this doesn't seem to work i just want the first thing to work I guess I tried 
```array = []
for role in roles:
    array.append(role['name'])

print(array) and it didn't work how can i have it to all names in roles print into an array?

Comment: @scraps it should work based on your sample data: https://ideone.com/VThxAx

Answer (score 0):

**The `jsonpath` package is dedicated to python processing json data.**

You just need to learn some simple syntax to operate.

```
from jsonpath import jsonpath

data = {
    "Label": "Color Roles",
    "Pool": "Colors",
    "Hidden": "false",
    "Limit": -3,
    "Message": "Pick a colored role to start with <3",
    "Roles": [
      {
        "Name": "Apple★",
        "Print": "Apple",
        "Aliases": ".iam Apple",
        "Aliases1": [
          ".iam Apple",
          "+Apple"
        ]
      },
      {
        "Name": "Clementine★",
        "Print": "Clementine",
        "Aliases": [
          ".iam Clementine",
          "+Clementine"
        ]
      },
      {
        "Name": "Sunflower★",
        "Print": "Sunflower",
        "Aliases": [
          ".iam Sunflower",
          "+Sunflower"
        ]
      },
      {
        "Name": "Mint★",
        "Print": "Mint",
        "Aliases": [
          ".iam Mint",
          "+Mint"
        ]
      },
      {
        "Name": "Ocean★",
        "Print": "Ocean",
        "Aliases": [
          ".iam Ocean",
          "+Ocean"
        ]
      },
      {
        "Name": "Grape★",
        "Print": "Grape",
        "Aliases": [
          ".iam Grape",
          "+Grape"
        ]
      },
      {
        "Name": "Candy Floss★",
        "Print": "Candy Floss",
        "Aliases": [
          ".iam Candy Floss",
          "+Candy Floss"
        ]
      }
    ]
  }

print(jsonpath(data, "$..Name"))
```

out

```
['Apple★', 'Clementine★', 'Sunflower★', 'Mint★', 'Ocean★', 'Grape★', 'Candy Floss★']
```

Comment: friend helped me out and i fixed it with `array = [role['Name'] for role in data['Role']]`